# Connect to currently active tab in Chrome with puppeteer-core

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

I am using `puppeteer-core` and connect to my own chrome installation. That works fine, but how can I execute commands on the currently active tab? how to get a reference to it?

```
const wsChromeEndpointurl = 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/12345';
const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: wsChromeEndpointurl
});

const page = <active tab> // what do I need here?
```

(My goal is to do some things like logging in to a website manually, then let `puppeteer` take over. So I really want to use `puppeteer-core`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct API to solve this but you can iterate through the `pages` array and evaluate the `visibilityState` property of the document.

```js
async function activePage() {
  const allPages = await context.pages();
  for(let page of allPages) {
    const state = await page.evaluate(() => document.visibilityState);
    if(state === 'visible') {
      return page;
    }
  } 
}
```